# Design patterns: exception / error handling

Tags: design-patterns, exception

Is there any resource (web or book) describing exception handling / error handling design patterns?

There is a lot of literature on how to write clean code, and there are a lot of books covering design patterns. I have, however, never seen any design pattern covering the issue of where and how best to handle errors and how best to propagate an error appearing in a low-level function up the levels of abstraction.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

These patterns and best practices are often bound to a specific platform/language, so they are the first place to look for them.

- [Exception patterns wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExceptionPatterns) is a general patterns resource.

As an example check the following links for java:

- [Best Practices for Exception Handling](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html)
- [15 Best practices about exception handling](http://codebuild.blogspot.com/2012/01/15-best-practices-about-exception.html)
- [Exception-Handling Antipatterns](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983543)

Going through such materials would give you a general idea to follow in exception handling mechanisms.

Also check other SO questions:

- [Exception handling pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589750/exception-handling-pattern)
- [Java Style: Properly handling exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425281/java-style-properly-handling-exceptions?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Best approach is never to swallow any exceptions within your application code.  Hookup a handler to unhandled exceptions in your applications when bootstrapping where you can show an error message and do some logging.

Some decent books i've read recommended this approach.

http://thibautvs.com/blog/?p=2238 is a good one where it's mentioned.

Comment: The link above is stale... Try this one: https://books.google.de/books/about/Framework_Design_Guidelines.html?id=39d1wZ598ecC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 2):

Because this question is about design patterns. I'd there is not one pattern but two.

1. Observer Pattern
2. Decorator Pattern

Generally a try/catch/finally block is written for handling exception which could go terribly wrong very soon.
If you are logging exception in catch block you have got it wrong already.
If you are trying to recover from the exception and continuing the code flow then you are right.
If you didn't expect the exception and chose to ignore then you are doing the right thing.

Also, who do you write exception handler for. There are at least 3 audience of an exception.

1. The end user. The end user wants to know what went wrong and what he is supposed to do next.
2. The support team. When the end user reaches out the support team is supposed to give him a satisfactory answer.
3. Finally third, us, the developers. We would want to know what were the variables/function/stack trace when the crash happened. So that we can diagnose and make fixes.

There could definitely be more parties interested in the exception but at least these three.

All these audience have separate exception handling requirements.
User wants to a see a friendly message, support wants to know next steps. and developers wants to see stack traces for fixing it.

This makes exception not a single function but a series of event handlers. One for each participant (Observer pattern).

Because we follow DRY principles we don't want to repeat the try/catch/finally block in all the functions. So we write a decorator class. This class is an implementation of Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP).

One generic class that is decorating all the class (from specific assembly at boundary of application) using reflection. And one single try/catch/finally block inside decorator to take care of the th

Comment: What about generating an email for a manual team to continue a booking flow. They need what ever information was captured up until that point. Some information when the catch occurs isn’t committed to database. I’m just calling sendEmail in a catch with references to all the objects. It’s disgusting but I’m not sure what other options to go with. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sigex 
Multi-step code always runs through a State Pattern.

Like a ceiling-fan regulator: You can only go from Off->1->2->3->Off 
The important object in a state pattern is the `Context` object.
With each step progress update the context object.
And the final exception handler could use this context object to generate the email body.

Comment: Another pattern: Chain of responsiblity:  
```IBookingProgress 
{ 
  public User User {get; set;}
  public Address Address {get; set;}
  public Payment Payment {get; set; }
  public Booking Booking {get; set; }

  void UpdateProgress();
}```

And each step updates relevant members of the progress so far.

And when the application crashes the exception handler simply prints this data.

It'll also require the context object for the entire flow.

Comment: I know this isn't the right place to do this but I'd really like to reach out to you @ZiaullahKhan . Could you message me? Here's my email: uchenna19of@gmail.com

Comment: @Adophilus I am available on linkedin here: https://www.linkedin.com/in/ziaullah-khan/

Answer (score 0):

Description of using exceptions on .NET (but not only) in details: 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/5b2yeyab(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/5b2yeyab%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

When one should use them, how to write them, how to handle them correctly and so forth...