# How should I do this without throwing exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

I'm fairly new to Java, and I'm trying to get my head around exceptions and when they should be used. I have been using them as a form of error checking, but I've come across several people saying that exceptions should only be used for things out of the program's control, such as user error.

I have a function which, for a given line in 2 dimensions, calculates all the y values between xMin and xMax. This function throws an exception if the line is vertical, as it is impossible to calculate all values of y on a vertical line. There is an equivalent function finding points between two y values as well, which throws an error if the line is horizontal.

```
findPointsInRangeOfX (int xMin, int xMax) throws LineIsVerticalException {
    // check if line is vertical
    // if vertical, throw an exception
    // else calculate the y values for each integer between xMin and xMax
    // return y values
}
```

I call this function as part of finding all the points on a line within a given window, given by a minimum and maximum x and y value. I don't check whether the line is vertical in this function; instead, I rely on the checking in findPointsInRangeOfX and use a try and catch block around the method.

```
pointsInWindow (int xMin, int xMax, int yMin, int yMax) {
    try {
        // Find list of all the points between xMin and xMax.
        // Remove from list all points not between yMin and yMax
    }
    catch (LineIsVerticalException e) {
        // If line is vertical, cannot find points between xMin and xMax
        try {
            // Instead, find list of all points between yMin and yMax
            // Remove from list all points not between xMin and xMax
        }
        catch (LineIsHorizontalException e) {
            // This part will never be reached because the line is vertical
            // But the compiler complains if the exception isn't caught
        }
    }
}
```

Is this ok? I'm not throwing the exception for an error as such - there's nothing wrong with having a vertical line - but I'm using it to tell pointsInWindow that it needs to find the points between the y values rather than the x values. Should I be duplicating the check to see if the line is vertical in the pointsInWindow function rather than using a try catch block? If I did duplicate the check, should I get rid of the LineIsVerticalException all together?

Comment: You might find some of this stack flow on when to throw exceptions interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127/when-to-throw-an-exception as well as this one with links to other material http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542608/design-patterns-exception-error-handling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to adhere to the single responsibility principle: every method does one thing.
Right now your methods do two things: check if it's vertical/horizontal and calculate something.

Another note here: don't use exceptions for program flow.

You should split it up to something like this:

```
bool isVertical(parameters){}
bool isHorizontal(parameters){}
SomeClass CalculateVertical(parameters){}
SomeClass CalculateHorizontal(parameters){}
```

Your program flow could look like this:

```
if(isVertical(something)){
 CalculateVertical(something);
else if (isHorizontal(something)){
 CalculateHorizontal(something);
}
```

Example implementation:

```
SomeClass CalculateVertical(something){
 if(!isVertical(something)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException() }
 // Calculations
}
```

Note that this exception doesn't have to be caught by the programmer.

Comment: Agreed. I would be lazy and just throw IllegalArgumentException. It's an existing Exception and it's unchecked. It would force the user to validate input before attempting to call the methods.

Comment: So should I assume in CalculateVertical that I've definitely been given a vertical line, and not have any checking in that method?

Comment: @Emma: you should never trust the user. I would call `isVertical` again in `CalculateVertical` and throw an exception (like `IllegalArgumentException` as Kayaman says) if it returns `false`.

Comment: @Emma You can again check isVertical in the CalculateVertical method

Comment: But then, if I'm throwing an exception from CalculateVertical, I'll have to use try catch in pointsInWindow anyway - so then I'm back at the same point as I was before, just with an extra call to isVertical in there. Unless I've misunderstood something?

Comment: You don't have to catch `IllegalArgumentException`, it's an unchecked exception. It's the responsibility of the programmer to call the `isVertical` method first, you're just performing a final check.

Comment: Ok, thank you! So the final solution is to perform my own checks, without using exceptions, and as a final resort throw an unchecked exception. Will do! And apologies for being so slow to get it, you've been very helpful.

Comment: That's exactly the solution, yes :) It's okay, we've all been there.

Answer (score 1):

or you can modify like below:

```
pointsInWindow (int xMin, int xMax, int yMin, int yMax) {
    try {
        // Find list of all the points between xMin and xMax.
        // Remove from list all points not between yMin and yMax
    }
    catch (LineIsVerticalException e) {
        // If line is vertical, cannot find points between xMin and xMax
        // do something..
        }
    catch (LineIsHorizontalException e) {
        // unless LineIsVerticalException is superclass of LineIsHorizontalException,
        // this will work 
        // do something ..
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general I try to use Exceptions for unexpected problems (e.g. network failure) as opposed to just border cases. It is however a blurry distinction and depends on your specific application context.

Specifically for your problem. What about splitting the functionality. Make two functions that detect whether or not a given line is horizontal or vertical (e.g. boolean isVertical());.

In your pointsInWindow function you could then check first whether you are dealing with the special case of a vertical/horizontal line and if not call further to the findPointsInRange methods.

Try never to duplicate logic as this violates the DRY principle [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and tends to cause problems further on when maintaing your code.

Hope this helps,
Markus

Answer (score -1):

```
findPointsInRangeOfX (int xMin, int xMax) throws LineIsVerticalException {
    if(isLineVeritical(xMin, xMax)){
        throw new LineIsVerticalException();
    }

    return calculateValuesBetweenMinAndMax(xMin, xMax);
}
```